# Calculate Year on Year, Quarter on Quarter, Month on month number of Repeated, new, lost customers & theri revenue using pandas/python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've the customer's purchase details, here is the data structure I've

[image]

I'm trying to get year on year how many total number of customers and among them how many are new, repeated, lost customers and their revenue using pandas. I'm also looking for Quater on Quarter and Month on Month later.

Here is the expected output template.

[image]

I'm familiar with pandas and I'm blank after group by with order date how to proceed further. Even I was thinking is it possible with pandas/python to get these rolling measures?

I researched a lot but the found solutions are not the robust. [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/sales-report-in-pandas-c4ef777cc490) is one among them using pandas, and this is using [sql](https://www.sisense.com/blog/use-self-joins-to-calculate-your-retention-churn-and-reactivation-metrics/) where users tried to do the cross-join, which is not ideal when we have large data sets.

Can someone please help me to get a reasonable ideal solution using pandas/python for this problem please?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score -3):

This should work as a starting point and you can include custom functions via .apply() after a groupby to map lost customer counts and revenues.

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

example = """
    customer    order_num   order_date  revenue year    previous_year
0   1   1   2001-03-02  3.7568075947151836  2001    2000
1   1   0   2001-07-05  26.100814373150747  2001    2000
2   0   0   2000-01-25  81.42727909292141   2000    1999
3   0   0   2002-10-27  84.57343031759379   2002    2001
4   1   0   2002-02-18  23.671899087103267  2002    2001
5   0   1   2002-09-25  74.49165102681509   2002    2001
6   0   1   2000-01-08  29.108785770121727  2000    1999
7   0   0   2000-11-17  58.09356390920113   2000    1999
8   1   1   2001-05-15  99.52589462159052   2001    2000
9   1   0   2002-12-08  44.19007228669444   2002    2001
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(example), sep='\s+')
df

customer_year_counts = df.groupby('year')['customer'].value_counts()
customer_year_flags = customer_year_counts.unstack().diff().replace({np.nan: False}).stack()
customer_year_flags[customer_year_flags != False] = True
df['previous_year_active_flag'] = df.set_index(['year', 'customer']).index.map(customer_year_flags)
df['previous_year_active_flag'] = df['previous_year_active_flag'].replace({np.nan: False})

df = df.groupby(['customer', 'year', 'previous_year_active_flag']).agg(
    customer_count=pd.NamedAgg(column='customer', aggfunc='count'),
    revenue=pd.NamedAgg(column='revenue', aggfunc='sum'),
).unstack()

df['customer_count_total'] = df['customer_count'].sum(axis=1)
df['revenue_total'] = df['revenue'].sum(axis=1)

df.columns = [f'{i}_previous_year_active_{j}' if j != '' else f'{i}' for i,j in df.columns]

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not looking for a summary by customer and year-wise. And also I see this approach will work only if we have 3 years data. Sorry, I couldn't able to accept your answer. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Why are you not looking for a summary by customer and year-wise?